# What does the "..." sign before the parameter variable mean in CakePHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments, cakephp-3.0

Start to explore new CakePHP 3 installation today. I saw the following function in the controller in CakePHP 3 with the new installation.

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public function display(...$path) {
        print($path);
    }
}
```

The printed result is as following:

```
Array (
    [0] => home
)
```

The `home` value comes from the following routing definition.

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
```

My question is what does the `...`sign before the parameter `$path`variable do? I have never seen that technique before.

Comment: In Java the `...` is used for an unknown number of parameters. What's the output of display if you send it 2 args?

Comment: Read Here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list